# C - Segmentation fault with recursion

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I am pretty new to C so this question might be stupid, but I don't really understand why a **recursive** function gives me **segmentation fault**, while another one (with just one parameter changed), gives me nothing. 
So, these are the functions, used to calculate the number of "**vette**" (name of variable in my source code), a number greater than all other successive numbers in the array (not counting the last one).

This is the **non-working** one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 6
int vette(int *a, int len, int lentot) {
  /* end of the array */
  if (lentot<=1) return 0;
  /* checked if the element is a vetta*/
  if (len == 1) {
    return 1 + vette(&a[1], lentot-1, lentot-1);
  }
  /* checking */
  if (*a>a[len-1])
    return vette(a, lentot-1, lentot); /* this line gives me seg fault */
  else
    return vette(&a[1], lentot-1, lentot-1);
}
/*trying the function*/
int main() {
  int a[6]={10,9,4,5,7,6};
  printf("%d", vette(a,N,N));
}
```

As you can see, I am using len and lentot as parametes to navigate into the function. But, for some reason that I don't understand, the function give me an error where I wrote "/* this line gives me seg fault*/.

At the same time, changing the variale of lentot-1 with len-1, that has same value at that moment and won't change the value of lentot, because it is in the parameter *int len*, so nothing should happen, but my code starts working perfectly.
Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 6
int vette(int *a, int len, int lentot) {
  /* end of the array */
  if (lentot<=1) return 0;
  /* checked if the element is a vetta*/
  if (len == 1) {
    return 1 + vette(&a[1], lentot-1, lentot-1);
  }
  /* checking */
  if (*a>a[len-1])
    return vette(a, len-1, lentot);
  else
    return vette(&a[1], lentot-1, lentot-1);
}
/*trying the function*/
int main() {
  int a[6]={10,9,4,5,7,6};
  printf("%d", vette(a,N,N));
}
```

I'd really appreciate to **understand** why this code is giving me this error, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Print the values of your variables when you enter the function.  That should tell you right away what's happening.

Comment: @dbush thanks a lot for the suggestion: the results are the correct values in the working one, but in the nonworking one there's a loop of the recursive function. lentot is always 5, and len is always 6. I don't undertand why, given that even in the working one len is 6 and lentot is 5 in one step of the recursive function!

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it at the start of the question but if something isn't clear just tell me! " So, these are the functions, used to calculate the number of "vette" (name of variable in my source code), a number greater than all other successive numbers in the array (not counting the last one)." So, for example, {4,6,1,2} has 1 "vette", that is 6, because is bigger than every successive number. I just need the number of "vette"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you a segmentation fault because of a stack overflow (no pun intended).  Your recursion never finishes.  The second parameter, `lentot-1`, does not decrease.  When you change it to `len-1`, it does.

Starting from your main program, in the first recursive call `len = lentot = 6`.  Then, in the second recursive call from the accused line, `len = 5` and `lentot = 6`.  The problem is that in the third one, it will still be `len = 5` and `lentot = 6`, and so on.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand why. Giving the functions *lentot -1* in the "place" of len, isn't equale to give len? So, won't *lentot - 1* become the new len in the function called? EDIT: Understood; I'm passing everytime the same variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added some more explanation.  You should really use a debugger or a `printf` to trace the values of your variables, should you encounter problems like this.